# How to create copy button using html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-programming, dynamic-html

Hii am new to javascript but by putting my all efforts I have written a javascript to copy text inside a `<p></p>` elements. In my website I need the copy button many times. But my javascript work for only one copy button. if I used it to another copy button it would copy the first button's respective `<p>/p>` text. My javascript

```
const copyButton = document.querySelector('.copyButton');
const copyalert = document.querySelector('.copyalert');

copyButton.addEventListener('click', copyClipboard);

function copyClipboard() {
  var copystatus= document.getElementById("randomstatus");
// for Internet Explorer

  if(document.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(copystatus);
    range.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    copyalert.classList.add("show");
    setTimeout(function() {copyalert.classList.remove("show")},700);
  }
  else if(window.getSelection) {
// other browsers

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(copystatus);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    copyalert.classList.add("show");
    setTimeout(function() {copyalert.classList.remove("show")},700);
  }
}
```

My html

```
<div>
   <h2 class="statusheading">Latest English quotes</h2>
  <div id="englishquotes">
   <div class="latestquotes">
       <p class=latest>life os good when hou have books</p>
       <button class="copyButton btn">Copy</button>
          <span class="copyalert">Copied!</span>
</div>
<div class="latestquotes">
       <p class=latest>Google is a open source library</p>
       <button class="copyButton btn">Copy</button>
          <span class="copyalert">Copied!</span>
   </div>
<div class="latestquotes">
       <p class=latest>Cat is better than dog</p>
       <button class="copyButton btn">Copy</button>
          <span class="copyalert">Copied!</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: A different approach: navigator.clipboard.writeText(newClipText) NOTE: check browser compatibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to let the system knows the id of the text you want to copy , e.g. p1, p2, p3.

Please try this

```
<div>
   <h2 class="statusheading">Latest English quotes</h2>
  <div id="englishquotes">
   <div class="latestquotes">

       <p><div id=p1>life os good when hou have books</div></p> 
       <button class="copyButton btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p1')">Copy</button>

</div>

 

<div class="latestquotes">

       <p><div id=p2>Google is a open source library</div></p>
       <button class="copyButton btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p2')">Copy</button>

   </div>

 

<div class="latestquotes">

       <p><div id=p3>Cat is better than dog</div></p>
       <button class="copyButton btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p3')">Copy</button>

   </div>
  </div>
  </div>


<script>


function copyToClipboard(var1){
    let val = document.getElementById(var1).innerHTML;
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox.style.left = '0';
    selBox.style.top = '0';
    selBox.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox.value = val;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.focus();
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);
    alert('text copied to clipboard, please use Ctrl-V to paste the data');

  }  


</script>
```

Comment: Can you make it possible without jQuery? Please

Comment: No problem. I have already revised my answer - not using jquery. Please try again.

Comment: works for me, I had to change .innerHTML to value for element with input tag

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a text area, append to body and apply execCommand function, then you can remove the textarea from your DOM, try this:

```js
function copyToClipboard(){
    let val = 'text to copy';
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox.style.left = '0';
    selBox.style.top = '0';
    selBox.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox.value = val;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox.focus();
    selBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox);
    alert('text copied to clipboard');
  }
```

```html
<button type=button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. it copies "text to copy" word if I click any button.

Comment: you can pass an argument to function copyToClipboard(argument){let val = argument}

Comment: Although I got answer, but I can't understand your code.

Comment: If you will to understand more about it, it's quite similar to the code [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/5675325) from Dean Taylor.

Answer (score 1):

Since `document.execCommand('copy')` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), you can use `navigator.clipboard.writeText`, just need to check for [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard#browser_compatibility), like Ragul CS said.
For more information, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript/30810322#30810322).

```js
copyButton.addEventListener("click", async function () {
    const code = 'text to copy';
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(code);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<button @click="copyMe('Copied')">Copy Your Code</button>
```

'''''

```
function copyMe(){
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("Copy Clipboard");
}
```

'''''''